# get response text of ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello I'm using a message API and I can not retrieve the answer that appears in the network block on my mozilla.

below my code

```js
function sendMessage(params){
            var url = 'https://api.1s2u.io/bulksms?username='+ params.username +'&password='+ params.password +'&mt=1&fl=0&sid='+ params.sid +'&mno='+ params.mno +'&msg='+params.msg;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: url,
                processData : false,
                contentType: false,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                complete: function (data) {
                    console.log('complete', data)
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log('message',xhr)
                    console.log('exeptcion', status, error)

                }
            })
        }
```

In mozilla I get this:

[image]

and in the console I get this:

[image]

I just want to recover code 050. please how?

Comment: only set console.log on success or complete then post the result

Comment: `processData : false,` does nothing unless you include `data` which you are not: remove it. `contentType: false,` is meaningless on a GET request: remove it. `async: false,` is deprecated and causes performance problems. Remove it.

Comment: Your console logs an error. What does it say? Since your picture just shows the word 'error' instead of the actual error.

Comment: in success I receive nothing. in complete I receive the same result as well as in error

Comment: Don't do this by using Javascript. Do it with PHP on server side that you have enough control over the interface and not need to share your account data with the client.

Comment: @shilly I had this error: A network error occured.
But it disappeared when I deleted the contenttype, async and process

Comment: @PascalWirtz how to do in php please

Comment: @isiPouchi i posted an anwser showing a way how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented above, I'd never do this only by using JavaScript, because it requires me to send my login credentials for the remote API to the client.

I'd do it by using a PHP script, that does the request to the remote API and outputs the result that I can read out with a javascript AJAX request.

On the server the "url_fopen" PHP feature needs to be enabled.
This method offers much more control over the API, because all data you may need for extensions can be stored on server side. For example a detection of too many send requests to or from a given mobile number or a custom account system that only allows sending messages for registered users, etc.

A quick solution would be doing somethling like i've done here:

Create a file named: send.php:

```
<?php

const USERNAME = "Username";
const PASSWORD = "Password";

$MNO = $_POST['mno'] ?? '';
$SID = $_POST['sid'] ?? '';
$MSG = $_POST['msg'] ?? '';

$HttpData = http_build_query(
    array(
        "username" => USERNAME,
        "password" => PASSWORD,
        "sid" => $SID,
        "mno" => $MNO,
        "msg" => $MSG
    )
);

$HttpRequest = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'GET',
            'header' => "Accept-Language: en\r\n"
        )
    )
);

$Response = array();
$Request = file('https://api.1s2u.io/bulksms?' . $HttpData, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES, $HttpRequest);
if($Request && count($Request) > 0) {   
    $Response['success'] = $Request[0]; 
} else {
    $Response['error'] = 'There was an error in the http request!';
}

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($Response);

?>
```

Your HTML will have to look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SMS Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>

        $(document).on('click', '#submitSms', function(e) {
            var mno = $("#mno").val();
            var sid = $("#sid").val();
            var msg = $("#msg").val();

            var error = false;
            if(mno.length < 3) { $("#mno").css("border-color", "red"); error = true; }
            if(sid.length < 3) { $("#sid").css("border-color", "red"); error = true; }
            if(msg.length < 3) { $("#msg").css("border-color", "red"); error = true; }
            if(error) return;

            $.ajax({
                url: 'send.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'sid=' + sid + '&mno=' + mno + '&msg=' + msg,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                    if(json['error']) {
                        $("#sendSms").prepend('<p style="color:red;">' + json['error'] + '</p>');
                    } else if(json['success']) {    
                        $("#sendSms").prepend('<p style="color:green;">' + json['success'] + '</p>');
                    }                   
                },
                error: function(xhr, opt, error) {
                    alert(error + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="sendSms">
            <p>MNO: <input type="text" name="mno" id="mno"></p>
            <p>SID: <input type="text" name="sid" id="sid"></p>
            <p>Message:<br><textarea name="msg" id="msg"></textarea></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submitSms" id="submitSms" value="Send" /></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This only a quick solution, there might be some security related aspects you need to handle on your own, because I don't know what your projects other parts look like.
Post Sender-ID, Message and MobileNo to send.php that will contain your login details and will do the Request to the other API you want to use. It outputs JSON encoded data, containing the keys "error" or "success". "error" is set after a failed request to the remote API and success is initialized with the output ot that remote API, if the request was successful.

You only need to handle the remote API error codes in JS (or in send.php).